# Why must I re-save a file from Mac in order for it to work?

Tags: terminal, finder, encoding

I have an issue for which I have a work-around solution. I'm hoping to eliminate the work-around to improve production efficiency.

My associate's server automatically runs a script that outputs a large file of research data (all text) in a `json` string and saves it as a huge (4MB+) `.json` file.

I retrieve this file via ftp. My understanding is that the ftp software (Fetch) delivers the file to me just as it was saved.

**When I try to process the file contents (from Terminal) using a Python script, I receive this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/client drop folders/client1/pythonScript.py", line 61, in <module>
    sourceData = json.loads(line.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2547902: invalid continuation byte
```

The character at this position is a space — though that seems moot, considering my work-around:

**My work-around is simply opening the file and resaving it** (either by using VSCode's standard save dialogue OR by simply using my Mac's TextEdit and choosing to save with `utf-8` character encoding and a `.json` extension) and overwriting the file.

**The Python file processes the json with no errors after this re-saving of the source file.**

If I run `file -I sourceFile.json` on the save before re-saving it, then it produces:

`sourceFile.json: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

After the re-save, the same Terminal command produces the same:

`sourceFile.json: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

**Why would the file perform differently before and after re-saving it?**

I would appreciate any knowledgeable advice or answers. Is there a better troubleshooting method than the Terminal `file -I` command?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Appendices:**

diff output:

```
1c1
< (entire content of file 1 from server)
\ No newline at end of file
---
> (entire content of file 2 saved on Mac)
\ No newline at end of file
```

cmp output:

```
old/file.json new/file.json differ: char 2547903, line 1
```

Comment: 0xc3 isn't a space, it's Ã [which is often one of those letters that appears randomly in badly-made movie subtitles;) Space is 0x20.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see a binary compare of the files before save and after save, but basically you're having the file make a round trip through some editor that is not binary-safe (VS Code certainly is not).  So the file was interpreted, and then written out again.

Comment: @MarcWilson I'm not an expert on binary comparison, but I have added some "appendices" above with output from ```diff``` and ```cmp``` commands. I'm still working on this, and my suspicion is that Tetsujin is somewhat on the right track. I will update this question if it comes to anything, but any suggestions in the meantime would appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: The cmp shows that it does change n VSCode.  Bascially the original file is not valid utf-8 iwe need to see hex dumps around char 2547903 You need to look at the task generating the file.

Comment: What does VS Code change the offending byte to?

Comment: @MarcWilson There is no visual change. I've run hexdumps as mmmmmm suggests, plus some xxd analyses, but they don't tell me anything. I am going to follow mmmmmm's advice and see if I can have a look at the originating php script that built this monster. I shall report back — prolly a few days.

Comment: @MarcWilson and mmmmmm You guys must think I'm a troubleshooting n00b! I was able to get the "builder" script from the source server. As mmmmmm predicted, the script missed out running the text through php's utf8 encoder: the simple function ```utf8_encode``` Many thanks to both of you. You've steered me towards some excellent and new-to-me trouble-shooting tools here. If either of you want to post an answer, I'll swing by in a few days and approve, upvote, laud and magnify! Best.

Comment: Go for it. It's perfectly acceptable, & even encouraged, to write your own answer. We gave the hints, you did the leg-work. Take the credit too. Also… I don't need the points. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin Haha! Well said, though I do feel like I should be throwing alms at the feet of all those who helped. Cheers; and thanks again.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as accepted too - extra points in it for you & signifies to others the question has a 'correct' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the issue was that the source file was indeed *not* saved with utf-8 encoding, despite what `file -I` indicated. I was able to examine the `php` script which produced the original `json` output and was also able to pass the text through the `php` function `utf8_encode` to solve the problem.

If others in this forum are having similar difficulties, I highly recommend reading through the comments on the opening question, as they provide good troubleshooting tools and advice.